# How to show a different image in each row based upon section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have one `UITableview`, and in that table there are many sections. Now I have to set different images for different section's rows. I know how to set different images for different row in a section but here I have to set different images on different section's row?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == yourSection) {
     if(indexPath.row == yourRow) {
     // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

Use this basic logic to customize according to your needs. In case of large numbers its better to go with `switch case` rather than `if-else`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sotreKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];


    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView 
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];


    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row ==0)
    {
        /*Add image on section of cell*/
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row ==1)
    {
        /*Add image on section of cell*/
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row ==1)
    {
        /*Add image on section of cell*/
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
}
```

use this i think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this. I find this to be the best way, if you are going to store the images in an array.

Store the images in an array of arrays so that you can index it with both section and row and access it something like this. The number of arrays should be the number of sections. If you are gonna change the number of sections and/or rows dynamically, I suggest you use NSMutableArray. If not, NSArray will work fine.

You can now set those images from methods like cellForRowAtIndexPath: or any method where you know the indexPath of the cell to be loaded with one line like

```
[[imagesSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

rather than needless switch/if statements. I might also add that switch/if never works out well in loading cells for tableviews, but comes pretty handy when used on tablview, to identify which tableview requires a cell.

If you need to store images in a different way, please specify so that I can try and come up with a better solution.